# Optimizing spacing given surface area

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I'm trying to solve a problem on spacing between people occupying a given surface area. If I own a restaurant that is 5000 square feet, not necessarily rectangular, I'd like to figure out an algorithm that takes a given surface area, a given number of people and solve for the maximum distance I can space people out and still fit N number of people in the restaurant.

I've tried (surface area / N people) ^ 2 but that only works for moderate sized values of N. Small values large values of N end up spacing people closer together than required.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have the algebraic representation of the surface area; given by some algebraic constraints? If yes, this can be formulated as an optimization problem.

Comment: I don't have an algebraic representation. Precision isn't terribly important for my usuage, I'm mainly just looking for a ballpark. Would treating the surface area as a rectangle simplify the problem?

Comment: Yes, a lot! Suppose that you have the algebraic representation of the surface area $A$, given by a bunch of constraints. Then what you are looking for is finding $N$ points in $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ which have the maximum distance from each other. This can be mathematically formulated as follows:
$$\max\sum_{i,j\in [N]} \|u_i-u_j\|_2^2  \quad \text{ subject to } \quad u_i\in A.$$

For the rectangle, $A=\{u=(u_1,u_2)\in \mathbb R^2 \, |\, x_i\le u_i\le y_i, \, \forall i=1,2\}$.
A close problem is the $k$-center clustering problem.